# Is [date] a tag that needs some fixing?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed something about the [date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/date) tag.  It has questions regarding the date/time indicator, getting date/revision info from a file/folder metadata, and has been included on questions regarding "cron tab output".

In my opinion, some of these tags are wrong, as I have seen a tag about the date-time indicators, and tags about file-related items.

As well, [date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/date) has no tag wiki, so its purpose could be interpreted incorrectly.

Anyone got any opinions on whether this needs fixing or removal?

Comment: Retagging questions to have more specific and clear tags sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: @AnnaLear i have absolutely no time on my hands to go and retag the questions, but should [tag:date] be destroyed by fire?  its one of those tags which incorporates several other (better) flags in it, so...

Comment: If we just remove the tag, you'll end up with questions that aren't tagged with anything useful at all or that are missing a useful tag. From a technical standpoint, we certainly *can* remove the tag, but it'd have to be pretty supported by the community here. A more typical approach is to go through the questions and retag them where appropriate or at least make a list of which questions should be retagged with what tags. You don't have to be the one doing it -- someone else from the community could step up. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear i meant with the *implied assumption* that someone actually redoes the tags on those 300+ questions before we burn the tag.  Having said that, is there any way to prevent *new* questions from being tagged with [tag:date] so that we can retag the older questions that have it, but not have an increase in the number of questions who have the aforementioned tag)